# Does $(x^m)^n$ not always equal $x^{mn}$?

Tags: exponentiation, fake-proofs

I was messing around and "proved" that $|x|=x$:
$$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}=x^\frac{2}{2}=x^1=x.$$
Now clearly this cannot be true unless $x$ is non-negative. The error seems to be going from the second equality to the third. However, using our exponent rules,
$$\sqrt{x^2}=(x^2)^\frac{1}{2}=x^\frac{2}{2}$$
should be true. What is the problem with this "proof"?

Comment: @T.Bongers No what?  No not? Or no yes. Double negative?

Answer (score 3):

The rule$$a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$$holds when $a>0$ and $b,c\in\mathbb R$. Otherwise, what does it even *mean*? What is $(-1)^\frac12$, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the rule:
$$(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$$
for $a,b \in \Bbb R$ (and not $\Bbb Z$) is only valid for $x \geq 0$.

And indeed for $x \geq 0$, $|x|=x$.

In all generality it is a bad idea to take non integer power if there is a negative number.